# Multiple Silverlight animations crushing

Tags: c#, silverlight, task, multithreading

I have 2 custom controls in my silverlight application and each one is having its own animations. I want to play all of the animations in order but when they play at the same time, the animations are not playing properly. How can I put some delay between them?

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { 
myCustomControl1.Play();
Thread.Sleep(200);
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { myCustomControl2.Play(); });
        }
```

Comment: Are these custom controls something you've written (local code) or something that has been purchased from a third party (Telerik, Infrasgistics, etc)?

Comment: my own controls. They are very simple just some image controls and mediaelements are there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your controls are using a StoryBoard to play the animations.  StoryBoard has a "Completed" event that fires after it completes running.  So, you could do something like:

```
public class CustomControl:Control
{
public override void ApplyTemplate()
{
   _storyBoard=GetTemplateChild("AnimationStoryBoard") as Storyboard;
   _storyBoard.Completed+=OnCompleted;
}
public event eventhandler AnimationCompleted;

public void Play()
{
   _storyBoard.Begin();
}

private void OnCompleted(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if(AnimationCompleted!=null)
        AnimationCompleted(this,EventArg.Empty);
}
}
```

What you can then do is chain your animations together:

```
myCustomControl1.AnimationCompleted+=RunSecondAnimation;
myCustomControl1.Play();

private void RunSecondAnimation(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    myCustomControl2.Play();
}
```

Now we can guarantee that animation 2 will always happen after animation 1.

Comment: how can i put some delay between them ? Why doesnt Thread.Sleep work ? My animations are created dynamically.

Comment: OK. I put an event handler to custom controls to control animation. It works fine now. Thanks a billion. I think I need some best practises for silverlight threading though.